# NavigationDrawer cannot be cast toInterface

Tags: java, android, mobile

am trying to implement an interface to pass data between fragments and I got stuck here am making on click listener on recycler view and when there is a selection I want the value to be displayed in another fragment

```
2020-10-16 00:17:21.541 21250-21250/com.example.iszo_dev E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.iszo_dev, PID: 21250
    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.iszo_dev.Activity.NavigationDrawer cannot be cast to com.example.iszo_dev.Interface.Communicator
        at com.example.iszo_dev.Activity.ui.home.MenuCardFragment$2.onBindViewHolder(MenuCardFragment.java:197)
        at com.example.iszo_dev.Activity.ui.home.MenuCardFragment$2.onBindViewHolder(MenuCardFragment.java:161)
        at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:122)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7065)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7107)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6012)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6279)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1627)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3851)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4404)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17838)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5754)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1762)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17838)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5754)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:383)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:321)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17838)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5754)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.layoutDecoratedWithMargins(RecyclerView.java:9587)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1685)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3851)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4404)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17838)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5754)
        at androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2.onLayout(ViewPager2.java:527)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17838)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5754)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1982)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1826)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1735)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17838)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5754)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:383)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:321)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17838)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5754)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1762)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17838)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5754)
2020-10-16 00:17:21.542 21250-21250/com.example.iszo_dev E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.material.appbar.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:148)
        at com.google.android.material.appbar.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:43)
        at com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1996)
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:918)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17838)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5754)
        at androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1231)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17838)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5754)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:383)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:321)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17838)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5754)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1982)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1826)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1735)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17838)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5754)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:383)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:321)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17838)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5754)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1982)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1826)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1735)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17838)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5754)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:383)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:321)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:751)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17838)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5754)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2711)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2384)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1462)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6965)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:907)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:709)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:644)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:893)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6251)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
```

and:

```
  public class MenuCardFragment extends Fragment {
    ...
    
       protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MenuCardFragment.ItemViewHolder itemViewHolder, int position, @NonNull final Items item) {
    
                    String categorie = getArguments().getString("categorie");
                    final String foodType = item.getFoodType();
    
                    if (shop_type == null) {
                        shop_type = "Shop";
                    }
    
                    final String itemName = item.getItemName();
                    final String itemPrice = item.getItemPrice();
                    final String itemType = item.getItemType();
                    final String btw = item.getBtw_tarif();
    
                    if (itemPrice.equals("sub")) {
                        itemViewHolder.makeSubCategoryRow(itemName);
                        itemViewHolder.mView.findViewById(R.id.subcategory_row_text).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        itemViewHolder.mView.findViewById(R.id.item_sub).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        itemViewHolder.mView.findViewById(R.id.item_single_amount).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        itemViewHolder.mView.findViewById(R.id.single_display_nr).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        itemViewHolder.mView.findViewById(R.id.item_display_single_name).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        itemViewHolder.mView.findViewById(R.id.item_single_amount).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        itemViewHolder.mView.findViewById(R.id.item_display_single_price).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        return;
                    }
                   itemViewHolder.mView.findViewById(R.id.subcategory_row_text).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    
                    final Communicator communicator = (Communicator)getActivity();
                    itemViewHolder.setRowNumber(position);
                    itemViewHolder.setItemName(itemName);
                    itemViewHolder.setItemPrice(itemPrice);
    
                    itemViewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            communicator.sendToBill(itemName, itemPrice, foodType, itemType, btw);
                            itemViewHolder.updateAmountField();
    
                        }
                    });
                    itemViewHolder.mView.findViewById(R.id.item_sub).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            itemViewHolder.updateAmountFieldForRemove();
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
    
    
    }
```

Comment: post the stacktrace

Comment: i update with stack trace

Comment: Check this line: `com.example.iszo_dev.Activity.ui.home.MenuCardFragment$2.onBindViewHolder(MenuCardFragment.java:197)`

Comment: final Communicator communicator = (Communicator)getActivity();  
this is the line and i think the getActivity(); is the problem but how can i initalise the interface

Comment: Does your Activity extend or implement Communicator?

Comment: i did it and now it works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

The issue is:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.iszo_dev.Activity.NavigationDrawer cannot be cast to com.example.iszo_dev.Interface.Communicator at
```

It depends by `final Communicator communicator = (Communicator)getActivity();`

You `Activity` has to extend or implement `Communicator`.